# Uploading an image to Etsy returns "metadata doesn't look like a _FILES array"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, etsy

I am having troubles uploading an image to Etsy through my Ruby on Rails app.
Following the [Etsy API](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/images) and the [Etsy gem](https://github.com/kytrinyx/etsy/tree/master/lib/etsy), I send a post request to `/listings/#{listing_id}/images`. The params are:

```
{:require_secure=>true, 
:image=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20150928-12064-1ctbfdu.jpg>, :type=>"image/jpg",
:multipart=>true, 
:listing_id=>249197834}
```

However, I get this error:

> 'The image array metadata doesn't look like a _FILES array'

Comment: Not sure but this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282899/etsy-image-add-returning-500-error-metadata-doesnt-look-like-a-files-array . Seems like issue related to authentication.

Comment: No, the problem was the multipart post. I fixed it by using the [oauth-multipart](https://github.com/aotianlong/oauth-multipart) gem

Answer (score 0):

According to [Etsy image gem](https://github.com/kytrinyx/etsy/blob/master/lib/etsy/image.rb), only send three parameter image, multipart and listing_id. You can set params like.

```
{
 image: open('/tmp/RackMultipart20150928-12064-1ctbfdu.jpg'),
 multipart: true,
 listing_id: 249197834
}
```